# 3 Legged Oauth2.0 For API Integration

Tags: api, oauth, constants, contacts

I'm trying to integrate an API (Constant Contact) http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/developer-guides/authentication.html#server-flow . The API requires that the URI that is incoming matches the one on the account, It won't because I am building a multi-user application that is mutli-domain.

I heard that 3 legged Oauth is the answer, but I can't find any documents or how-to's. This is what I think will work, but correct me if I'm wrong:

Client's site ----> My confirm server (insert API Key & Secret Here) ----> API Server
Client Accepts <-----------| confirm server directs user key back |---------<

So I am very confused. I can send the GET information from client site to my confirm server just fine. But I just get so confused about how it stores where the request came from after the confirm server sends the request to the API server. How does it keep it? How does it redirect? How does it send the key back again?

I'm relatively new to this concept. Thank you for any reading/help.